# Why does cout return smanip?

Tags: c++, iomanip

Could anyone explain me the declaration of the setw manipulator? I was completely blown off trying to understand it.! The declaration of the setw in iomanip is as follows

```
 smanip setw(int)
```

now what is smanip? what happens when we give std::cout << setw(10) << "Hai" [ i want to know how the output is actually affected by setw, in other words the actions happening under the hood)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`smanip` is an implementation-defined type. The library can define or typedef it to anything it likes, as long as the job gets done.

In practice, it will be some kind of structure representing (a) the manipulation to be performed, and (b) the argument `10` to be used in this manipulation. It might also have a function to perform the manipulation, or it might not, depending how the implementation has defined `operator<<(ostream &, smanip)`, or some similar overload to catch the necessary operand types. I haven't checked my implementation to find out.

As for how the output is affected: `my_stream << setw(10)` is defined to have the same effect on the stream as calling `my_stream.width(10)`. So the `operator<<` overload will ensure that happens in some implementation-specific way. The operator overload for non-parameterized stream manipulators is defined specifically to call the manipulator, but with `smanip` there's a little more freedom for implementations.

Comment: void Function1 { std::cout.width(10); std::cout.fill('*'); }            int main() { Function1(); std::cout<<"hai"; return 0;} From the above snippet I can observe that the manipulators have function scope! Is this also implementation specific?

Comment: @Karthik: the effect of a manipulator doesn't have a lexical scope. When it's shifted onto the stream object, it modifies the stream object, then the settings persist in the stream object until they're reset. Your code should output `*******hai`, I don't think that's implementation-specific.

Answer (score 0):

`setw(int)` by itself doesn't modify anything. It simply returns a stream manipulator (smanip) that can be used to modify the stream's behaviour.

```
// setw example
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  cout << setw (10);
  cout << 77 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but do you know how it affects? in other words, smanip seems to be a templated class, but the decalation is smanip setw(int). Shouldnt it be smanip<int> setw(int) or something like that?